# Changes in html headers did not reflect after deployment

Tags: html

I here have two sets of lines of code in our project's html header obtained from using view source: one from local site and one from deployed site

Local:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/app.css" />
<!--[if lte IE9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/img/favicon.png" />
<script data-main="/assets/js/main.js" src="/assets/js/libs/require.js"></script>
```

Live:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/app.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/img/favicon.png" />
<script data-main="/assets/js/main.js" src="/assets/js/libs/require.js"></script>
```

The problem here is after we deployed the fix for IE 8,9 shown in this line:

```
<!--[if lte IE9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

we checked on IE, Chrome and Firefox if the codes already reflected on the live site. But after checking (view source) the said fix didn't reflect. I tried using ctrl+F5 because some of the solutions were done using this method due to some caching problems but unfortunately it still did not reflect.

What are other causes of this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by reloading the php5-fpm in our clouduser.

Answer (score 0):

this may be because of browser cache of your page. press reload to force browser to reload your page.